# Could not find 'price' in DJ4E assignment

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I've got a problem with DJ4E course by dr.Chuck. On Building Classified Ad Site #2 assignment my site can't pass a validation and checking form keeps throwing an error

> "Could not find 'price'
> The price field is missing on the create form - check the field_list in views.py"
> for URL http://meredan.pythonanywhere.com/ads/ad/create
> I have re-checked multiple times and can't find why this is raised, because price field is available in the UI and also present when I checked manually in a shell. I am not very experienced with Django, maybe I'm missing something, would appreciate any help.

creation class in `views.py`

```
class AdCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    template_name = 'ads/ad_form.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ads:all')
    def get(self, request, pk=None) :
        form = CreateForm()
        ctx = { 'form': form }
        return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

    def post(self, request, pk=None) :
        form = CreateForm(request.POST, request.FILES or None)

        if not form.is_valid() :
            ctx = {'form' : form}
            return render(request, self.template_name, ctx)

        # Add owner to the model before saving
        ad = form.save(commit=False)
        ad.owner = self.request.user
        ad.save()
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

My `forms.py`

```
class CreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    max_upload_limit = 2 * 1024 * 1024
    max_upload_limit_text = naturalsize(max_upload_limit)

    picture = forms.FileField(required=False, label='File to Upload <= '+max_upload_limit_text)
    upload_field_name = 'picture'

    class Meta:
        model = Ad
        fields = ['title', 'text', 'price', 'picture']  

    # Validate the size of the picture
    def clean(self) :
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        ad = cleaned_data.get('picture')
        if ad is None : return
        if len(ad) > self.max_upload_limit:
            self.add_error('picture', "File must be < "+self.max_upload_limit_text+" bytes")

    # Convert uploaded File object to a picture
    def save(self, commit=True) :
        instance = super(CreateForm, self).save(commit=False)

        # We only need to adjust picture if it is a freshly uploaded file
        f = instance.picture   # Make a copy
        if isinstance(f, InMemoryUploadedFile):  # Extract data from the form to the model
            bytearr = f.read();
            instance.content_type = f.content_type
            instance.picture = bytearr  # Overwrite with the actual image data

        if commit:
            instance.save()

        return instance

class CommentForm(forms.Form):
    comment = forms.CharField(required=True, max_length=500, min_length=3, strip=True)
```

My `ad_form.html`

```
{% extends 'base_menu.html' %}
{% block title %}{{ settings.APP_NAME }}{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<p>
  <form action="" method="post" id="upload_form" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form|crispy }}
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary ">
        <input type="submit" value="Cancel" class="btn btn-default" onclick="window.location.href='{% url 'ads:all' %}';return false;">
    </div>
  </form>
</p>
<script>
$("#upload_form").submit(function() {
  console.log('Checking file size');
  if (window.File && window.FileReader && window.FileList && window.Blob) {
      var file = $('#id_{{ form.upload_field_name }}')[0].files[0];
      if (file && file.size > {{ form.max_upload_limit }} ) {
          alert("File " + file.name + " of type " + file.type + " must be < {{ form.max_upload_limit_text }}");
      return false;
    }
  }
});
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Manually checking

> In [2]: CreateForm.Meta.fields Out[2]: ['title', 'text', 'price','picture']

Also tried cleaning cache of browser, Django cache, made migrations, disabled extensions